# Advanced Custom Fields missing Woocomerce in Rules

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to create a custom field in the Cart page, but in "Conditions" / "Rules" / "Show this product fields group if" of the Advanced Custom Fields plugin there’s no Woocommerce option.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a page template (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) were you specify the output for the cart page. Then you can select the new page template in the conditional rules.